# Finding the radius of a circle when a sphere is cut by a plane.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, spheres

This is the question: 
Let $S$ be the sphere of radius $14$ centered at the point $C(5, −3, 16)$.
(a) The plane $y = 3$ intersects $S$ in a circle. Where is the centre of this circle and what is its radius?

The center is easy to calculate, $(5,3,16)$
I have no clue of how to get the radius though.

Comment: Consider plugging $y=3$ into the equation of the sphere.

Comment: **Hint**: the intersection of the sphere $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2+(z-z_c)^2=r^2$ with the plane $y=y_0$ is the circle  $(x-x_c)^2+(z-z_c)^2=r^2-(y_0-y_c)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determine the distance of the points $C(5/-3/16)$ and $(5/3/16)$ , which is $6$ and denote it with $d$ ( d is the distance of $C$ from the plane). Then, the radius of the circle is $r'=\sqrt{r^2-d^2}=\sqrt{14^2-6^2}=\sqrt{160}=12.649$

Comment: Thank you that's correct, much appreciated !

Comment: I dont seem to understand why we subtracted 6^2 from 14^2, isnt the circle we're working the radius out for in the xz plane?

Comment: You get a triangle with an angle of $90°$ by the radius of the circle, the radius of ths sphere and the orthogonal projection from the mid-point of the sphere to the plane. So, you can apply Pythagoras's formula.

Comment: You're amazing thanks so much!